# SignalR client flutter library shows null values in another widget when using Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, signalr.client

Am trying to connect on a SignalR server with flutter, and I tried to use Provider to access the data which comes to another Widget, but am receiving a null value. This is the [SignalR](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client)  library for flutter am using.

Below is my **Class** which extends a `ChangeNotifier` :

```
class BreakingNewsSignalRClient with ChangeNotifier {
  String  _breakingNews;

  Future<void> getBreakingNews() async {
    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://services.xxxx.com/breakingNews')
        .build();
      await hubConnection.start();
      hubConnection.on("UpdateBreakingNews", (data){

        _breakingNews = data.toString();
        print(data.toString());

        notifyListeners();
      });
      hubConnection.onclose((error) => print("Connection Closed"));


  }

  String get breakingNewsFunction => _breakingNews;
}

class BreakingNewsModel {
  final String News;
  BreakingNewsModel(this.News);
}
```

As you can see the code above, am having a getter `String get breakingNewsFunction => _breakingNews;`,  this is called in another Stateful Widget to populate some data from the SignalR  server, but it returns null in the other widget, however, when you try to print data here in the `getBreakingNews` method the data is shown.

Below is another Widget class which receives the data :

```
class BreakingNews extends StatefulWidget {
  const BreakingNews({Key key, @required this.article, @required this.index})
      : super(key: key);
  final Article article;
  final int index;

  @override
  _BreakingNewsState createState() => _BreakingNewsState();
}




class _BreakingNewsState extends State<BreakingNews> {


  settings() async{
    var breakingNewsInfo =
    Provider.of<BreakingNewsSignalRClient>(context, listen: false);

    await breakingNewsInfo.getBreakingNews();

    print('lets see -- ${breakingNewsInfo.breakingNewsFunction}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    settings();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

So when you look at this line `print('lets see -- ${breakingNewsInfo.breakingNewsFunction}');`, it prints null, am still wondering what am doing wrong here.

Kindly need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `data[0]`?

Can you write it?

```
_breakingNews = data[0].toString();
```

instead of

```
_breakingNews = data.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple. Your `Future<void> getBreakingNews() async` returns void and therefore null. Just adjust the return type to whatever you need.

Edit:

Actually, the problem is you are not calling your getter here.

```
await breakingNewsInfo.getBreakingNews();
```

So either return your result from the function, or call the getter. Either should work.

Comment: Hey , Benedikt, thanks for your reply, Ok lets say I make the method returnable, how will I attach the returned data to the getter, maybe you can give me an illustration , with the code I shared. Thanks

Comment: The getter is the one in the print `print('lets see -- ${breakingNewsInfo.breakingNewsFunction}');`

Comment: How can I call a getter here , `await breakingNewsInfo.getBreakingNews();`, am abit confused ?

Comment: @IdrisStack sorry, I misread your code. I m checking again right now.

Comment: @IdrisStack after running ```breakingNewInfo.getBreakinfNews();``` the variable gets updated. so the getter should work

Comment: That is what I was expecting, but unfortunately, it prints null, am still wondering

Comment: And surprisingly, when you print in the anynomous function it works,  but it doesn't set :

```(data){

        _breakingNews = data.toString();
        print(data.toString());

        notifyListeners();
      });```